# Use a ListView as a Navigation bar in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

My application has a grid with two columns. In the left column, I have a ListView, with some items with data binding. On the Right I want to implement a View that will display content based on which item 
is selected on the ListView. How do I do that?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="LightBlue">
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Name="listView"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ClientCollection}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ClientName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to achieve that is to add a selectedItem property to you ViewModel, witch is binded to the selected item of your ListView, and make that property the dataContext of the Right View;
here is a an example :

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="LvListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding ClientCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Location" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1"  VerticalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding SelectedClient,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Name: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Age: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Location: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Location}"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and in the coresponding MainWindow.cs :

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Client _selectedClient = new Client();
    public Client SelectedClient
    {
        get { return _selectedClient; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedClient == value) return;
            _selectedClient = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Client> _clientCollection = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
    public ObservableCollection<Client> ClientCollection
    {
        get { return _clientCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (_clientCollection == value) return;
            _clientCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ClientCollection = new ObservableCollection<Client>()
    {
        new Client()
        {
            Name = "James",Age = 34, Location = "Paris"
        },
         new Client()
        {
            Name = "Joe",Age = 34, Location = "Us"
        },
         new Client()
        {
            Name = "Ann",Age = 34, Location = "Canada"
        },
    };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and don't forget to set the datacontext for the mainWindow View, in that case

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```